# Scala to Java conversions

Tags: java, scala, collections

I want to use a Map with Object's reference `==` comparison in Scala. In Java we have `java.util.IdentityHashMap` so I would like to use it. I did this:

```
  val channels: Map[String, Handler] = (new util.IdentityHashMap).asScala.toMap
```

The issue is the docuemntation only says that

> Converts a Java collection to the corresponding Scala collection

So it's not clear if it's just a view of the Java collection or a newly created `scala.collection`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you take a look at the implicit definitions for the specific [types](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.9.2/scala/collection/JavaConverters$.html), you can see `mapAsScalaMapConverter` is documented as:

> Adds an asScala method that implicitly converts a Java Map to a Scala mutable Map. **The returned Scala Map is backed by the provided Java Map and any side-effects of using it via the Scala interface will be visible via the Java interface and vice versa**.
>
> If the Java Map was previously obtained from an implicit or explicit
>   call of asMap(scala.collection.mutable.Map) then the original Scala
>   Map will be returned.

The bold printed part should answer your question.